# How do I change a function's qualifiers via conditional compilation?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I have a function that is capable of being implemented as a `const`:

```
#![feature(const_fn)]

// My crate would have:

const fn very_complicated_logic(a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
    a * b
}

// The caller would have:

const ANSWER: u8 = very_complicated_logic(1, 2);

fn main() {}
```

I'd like to continue to support stable Rust where it's not possible to define such functions. These stable consumers would not be able to use the function in a `const` or `static`, but should be able to use the function in other contexts:

```
// My crate would have:

fn very_complicated_logic(a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
    a * b
}

// The caller would have:    

fn main() {
    let answer: u8 = very_complicated_logic(1, 2);
}
```

How can I conditionally compile my code so that adventurous users of my crate could enable `const fn` support, stable users would still be able to use my code, and I don't have to write every function twice?

The same question should apply to the other modifiers of a function, but I'm not sure of concrete cases where these modifiers would change based on some condition:

- `default`
- `unsafe`
- `extern`
- `pub` (and other visibility modifiers)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Macros to the rescue!

```
#![cfg_attr(feature = "const-fn", feature(const_fn))]

#[cfg(not(feature = "const-fn"))]
macro_rules! maybe_const_fn {
    ($($tokens:tt)*) => {
        $($tokens)*
    };
}

#[cfg(feature = "const-fn")]
macro_rules! maybe_const_fn {
    ($(#[$($meta:meta)*])* $vis:vis $ident:ident $($tokens:tt)*) => {
        $(#[$($meta)*])* $vis const $ident $($tokens)*
    };
}

maybe_const_fn! {
    #[allow(unused)] // for demonstration purposes
    pub fn very_complicated_logic(a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
        internally_complicated_logic(a, b)
    }
}

maybe_const_fn! {
    fn internally_complicated_logic(a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
        a * b
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[cfg(feature = "const-fn")]
    #[test]
    fn use_in_const() {
        const ANSWER: u8 = very_complicated_logic(1, 2);
        drop(ANSWER);
    }

    #[test]
    fn use_in_variable() {
        let answer: u8 = very_complicated_logic(1, 2);
        drop(answer);
    }
}
```

Along with this in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
const-fn = []
```

Since macros can only expand to complete pieces of syntax (i.e. a macro cannot simply expand to `const`), we have to wrap the whole function in the macro and leave some parts of it unparsed so that we can inject `const` in the appropriate place. Then, the parser can parse the whole thing as a function definition.

Attributes and visibility qualifiers need special treatment, because they must appear before `const`. I am using the `vis` matcher ([available since Rust 1.30.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1300-2018-10-25)) to simplify the macro's implementation.